# WordPress Multisite domain mapping with different IPs

Tags: multisite, customization, domain-mapping, ip

Hey there, I have 5 different sites with 5 different IP's on cyberwurx shared account. How can I install wordpress multisite and use the domain mapping plugin and also keep my sites on different IP's?

Any ideeas?

Ty!

Comment: can your hosting account use 5 IP for the same server?

Comment: can u please explain?:( The hosting account gave me 5 differnt c class ips which i could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress won't care about the IPs, It's Apache's job to map IPs to your vhosts. You need to look at the Apache config: set up either 5 separate `VirtualHost` entries that all point to the same `DocumentRoot`, or tell Apache to listen on all available IPs, and use a wildcard match on a single `VirtualHost` section.